# Creating a record of data in excel

Tags: vba, excel, record

Currently I have an excel sheet that works out certain prices which change everyday. I would like to have a vba button that records everyday's prices for reference, saving the last price of the data everyday (I update the price frequently during the day)
I wrote the code below but seem to be getting the error:

> Compile error: Invalid Qualifier

[on the first `LastRow.Offset()` line]. I am quite new to vba and so any help would be appreciated

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Selecting the data to copy
Range("C23:O23").Select
Selection.Copy

'Find the last used row in Column B
Dim LastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'if still today, replace data, if not record the data on the next line
If LastRow = Date Then
    LastRow.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, 
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Else
    LastRow.Offset(1, 0) = Date
    LastRow.offset(1, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, 
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End If


End Sub
```

**UPDATE:** So, Ive changed a bit of my code where I define the LastRow variable differnetly:

```
Dim LastRow As Range
Set LastRow = Range("B31").End(xlDown)
```

This seemed to lead to a different error, "1004", in the line just after the else statement

```
LastRow.Offset(1, 0).Value = "=today"
```

Any advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LastRow is defined as Long

```
Dim LastRow As Long
```

And then you are trying to use an `Offset` method, which is only available on `Range` objects.

Make the following changes and you should be good to go.

```
Dim LastRow As Range
With ActiveSheet
    Set LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
End With
```

Reading this post on [how and why to avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) will take you far too. The code above can be optimized to work much smarter.

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it. I was double checking my work.

Comment: Doing that leads to a run-time error '91'...tried  with and without '.row' after the 'end(xlUp)'

Comment: @user1234 - read the link I provided and get rid of `select` and `activesheet`. Fully qualify your objects and work directly with them. I strongly suspect the error will go away if you adjust for my answer as well.

Comment: Add set before defining lastrow fixes everything

Comment: @user1234 - great point. I often forget that simple yet important syntax in my own coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo in your else statement:

`LastRow.oofset(1, 1).Select`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesnt seem to be it

Comment: Oops, just now saw you said the _first_ Lastrow.Offset line.